# Is it possible to control return type when using a JPA @Query select?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, polymorphic-associations

I have several polymorphic JPA entities, and I'm curious as to whether it's possible to do Polymorphic selects when using an @Query tag.

I've got some entities in roughly the following relationship:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class ParentObject {
    //common fields - it's CRM-like
}

@Entity
public class ChildObject extends ParentObject {
    //specific fields - a particular kind of case
}

@Entity
public class ChildObjectPartDeux extends ParentObject {
    //specific fields - another kind of case
}
```

I've then got a parent repository, something like:

```
@Repository
public interface IParentObjectRepository <T extends ParentObject> extends JpaRepository<T, Long> {
    Page<T> findAllByCommonField(Pageable page);
    @Query("SELECT p FROM ParentObject p WHERE someFiddlyConditionWhichNeedsAQueryTag")
    Page<T> aFiddlyQuery(Pageable page, Object someParameter);
}
```

The first definition works a treat, and other repositories which inherit from the ParentObject and associated repository work needn't provide their own ChildObject-specific version - they only return ChildObjects.

The second definition works as long as only one kind of child is present in the system, after which point everything goes south. My (potentially flawed) understanding is that as I am explicitly selecting from ParentObject in the @Query, this query also runs "as-is" when it's inherited, and there isn't a handler to cast ChildObjectPartDeux to ChildObject. Not that I'd want to do that, anyway.

Right now, I'm getting round this issue by overriding these @Query-tagged methods in the child repository and swapping out the object name, as shown below, but it feels like there should be a DRY-er way to do this:

```
@Repository
public interface IChildObjectRepository extends IParentObjectRepository<ChildObject> {
    @Query("SELECT c FROM ChildObject c WHERE someFiddlyConditionWhichNeedsAQueryTag")
    Page<ChildObject> aFiddlyQuery(Pageable page, Object someParameter);
}
```

The behaviour I'd hope for is similar to the first method, that the JpaRepository<TypeInHere, Long> dictates which kinds of item are due to be returned and inform which items should be selected. Is there a way to feed that into a @Query tag?